# Using boost threads when compiling with /clr

Tags: .net, c++, multithreading, clr

I have gave up on creating a GUI directly from the windows API so I'm going to use forms.  I would like to multithread my app and wrap the GUI in a class and put it in a separate thread.  When I click a button, etc, it would change a value in a struct that will be read from the main thread.  My problem is, when I compile my application I get an error with the linker.

```
1>Core.obj : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013119F) : A TypeRef exists which should, but does not, have a corresponding TypeDef: (dummy): (0x0100001f).
```

My code for main is as follows.

```
int main()
{
//create thread object pointer
    boost::thread *GUIThread;
//create pointer to GUIInterface, which contains a member function that
//contains the Application::Run
    GUIInterface *myinterface;
    myinterface = new GUIInterface;

    GUIThread = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&GUIInterface::MainFunction, myinterface));
    return 0;
}
```

It works fine when creating the class and calling the function in the main thread, but using boost causes problems.  I built boost using the correct compiler MSVC-10.0 and the threading library has always worked in the past, but clr just causes problems.
Any recommendations on how to fix this?
OR if I should just use .net multithreading(if I do, I really need some links to how to use in with c++, most stuff I find is in C#).
Thanks.

Comment: You are getting this error because boost::thread uses r-value references.  Not supported by the managed linker.  You are heading for a train wreck this way, a user interface is not something you can just bolt-on.  You must create a single-threaded apartment, a UI is fundamentally thread-unsafe.  Not sure how to keep you out of trouble.

Comment: Is it possible to build boost without rvalues?

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems when using `boost::thread` in a managed application.  The first is the linker error you encountered.  The second is an initialization error at application startup if the `boost::thread` implementation is statically linked with your application.

Both problems are mentioned in an [older bug report](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/2226#comment:2). I don't know if this has changed in later releases; 1.43 has the same problem.  I assume not as the case was closed `wontfix`.