# How to fix _CrtIValidHeapPoint(pUserData) assertion failure in c++ winforms application

Tags: c++, winforms, boost, clr

This is the first time I have ever used a site like this, but I am significantly stuck.
The background section that follows is included for completeness as I am not sure if any of the actions described within it may have contributed to the current problem I am facing.

**Background**

A colleague and I had written a whole lot of c++ code in a console application (with default settings) in visual studio 2010 (full version) for a university assignment.  We decided that we wanted to try our hand at a winforms application and so created one in visual studio 2010 and imported all our code from the console application.  We faced the following issues:

1. Needed to add our includes in the "stdafx.h" file and then #include "stdafx.h" in all our implementation files (.cpp's).
2. In places where we were using c++ strings (std::string), we had to change to managed system strings (System::String^) for CLR compatibility.
3. Changed the "Common language runtime support" compile option to /clr instead of /clr:pure.  This was needed to solve linking errors (LNK2028, LNK2019) we had with boost::shared_ptr ...

After we had done the above things our project was compiling.

**The Problem**

When we run the application we get the following assertion failure:

_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)

This assertion fails immediately, seemingly without any code being executed, as when I set breakpoints at the start of main they are not reached in debugging (call stack is empty).

The only way I have been able to get the application to run is by setting the CLR option to /clr:pure and removing all usage of boost.

I have 3 questions:

1. Is code being executed?  I know it sounds impossible that an assertion could be failing without code being executed.  Is there something that happens before main perhaps?
2. What do the /clr and /clr:pure options really mean?
3. Can boost libraries be compiled to clr compatible code? If so, what may cause linking issues?

Thank you all for your time, I have not posted any code because I literally don't know what to post...I have no idea where the issue is occurring.  If anyone has suggestions for what code to post, I am open to them.

Regards
Brad

Answer (score 1):

To try and answer your specific questions:

1. `main()` is the entry point to *your* code and not the entire executable. There may be a large amount of boilerplate initialization as well as initializing all global static objects. For example, in the follow example the the function is run before main is entered:

   ```
      int SomeGlobal = SomeFunction();

      int main (void)
      {
      ...
      }
   ```
2. I have near zero experience with /clr but I can point you at a few useful references. Make sure you understand everything that applies to you in [How To Migrate to /clr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173265%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and the [/clr settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s.aspx).
3. I again have no direct knowledge but [this forum post on boost::shared_ptr](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/a7c39e3d-8183-45b7-8dc7-619669040b80) and [this SO question on boost::thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649960/using-boost-threads-when-compiling-with-clr) seem to indicate there are some issues.

To further diagnose the issue I would try a few things:

- Start with an empty or "hello world" CLR project to make sure it compiles and runs.
- Try a simple sample using boost and see if that works at all or duplicates the issue.
- Try cleaning and doing a complete rebuild of your application.
- The `pUserData` may be from a CString destructor. Make sure all strings are migrated to managed system strings.
- If you simple samples work then it is a matter of adding to the samples until you duplicate the issue, or removing stuff from your application until the issue goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's quite late, but I found this question because I had the same problem.

Looking in another project I've working (not mine), I've found that the problem comes from the file: `opencv_ts248d.lib`. If you **delete it from your depencencies**, it'll work fine (I don't know why, guess the problem is in a function which belongs to it), so you'll have the following ones:

```
opencv_calib3d248d.lib
opencv_contrib248d.lib
opencv_core248d.lib
opencv_features2d248d.lib
opencv_flann248d.lib
opencv_gpu248d.lib
opencv_highgui248d.lib
opencv_imgproc248d.lib
opencv_legacy248d.lib
opencv_ml248d.lib
opencv_nonfree248d.lib
opencv_objdetect248d.lib
opencv_ocl248d.lib
opencv_photo248d.lib
opencv_stitching248d.lib
opencv_superres248d.lib
opencv_video248d.lib
opencv_videostab248d.lib
```

(I'm just including all them without focusing in what I need, except the one which results in the problem)

Hope it helps you