# CGAL 4.9 how to disable boost_thread with VS2015

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, clr, cgal

From the **CGAL** [documentation](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/installation.html) i can read:
*For Visual C++ versions **prior to 2015** Boost.Thread is required, so make sure to either install the precompiled libraries for your compiler or build libboost-thread and libboost-system.*

It turns out that Boost.Thread produces some problems when combined with Microsoft's CLR, therefore I would like to avoid using it for the moment.

[Using boost threads when compiling with /clr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649960/using-boost-threads-when-compiling-with-clr)

I am currently building **CGAL** in header only mode and using **Visual Studio 2015**, how can I disable the linking to boost.thread?

Comment: What happens if you don't link to boost? It says that boost.thread is required for versions prior to 2015, which implicitly means that you don't have to link with it for 2015.

Comment: I am not sure as for the moment I have not been able to compile without Boost.Thread, however it is likely that C++ implemenation from VS2015 already includes standard C++ std::thread object, so the boost implementation can be replaced. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241993/is-it-smart-to-replace-boostthread-and-boostmutex-with-c11-equivalents